# Loading file from USB into SageMath

Tags: sage

I can load a file from my desktop into my SageMath IPython window. But can't determine the correct path for a USB drive. Is there a specific path line needed for USB's?

SageMath version 8.6 and Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: What operating system? What version of Sage?

Comment: I updated the post with the info. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is really a question for StackOverflow which is for programming questions and not general software usage questions. You should probably ask questions like this at the sage-support mailing list or the Sage-specific ask.sagemath.org.  That said, it's not exactly clear what your question is. USB drives are mounted on Windows like another drive, as it is assigned a drive letter like "E". So a path to a file on your USB drive would be like `E:\path\to\file`. There's nothing special about it being a USB drive. Did you try something like this? If so what specifically went wrong?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for it being in the wrong place, I’m still figured out what falls under which category. When I load from the desktop I use: load(‘~/Desktop/filename’). I tried the same with the USB drive: load(‘~/E:/filename’) as well as load(‘users/username/E:/filename’). Both returned an error message (I can share the specific error message when I get back to my computer). I also tried using the USB name instead of and combined with E: